# Setting custom max and min height or width in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I know in CSS, you can set the `min-height` and `max-width` but when I try `min-h-10` and `max-h-10` it doesn't do anything in Tailwind CSS.

And this is what I have:

```html
<div class="flex-col justify-center">
    <div class="h-10 w-10 border bg-blue-300 block">
        h
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values like `min-h-10` and `max-h-10` aren't *valid* values in Tailwind CSS, the only valid values are `min-h-0`, `min-h-full`, `min-h-screen`, `min-h-min`, `min-h-max`, `min-h-fit`.

So, the only way to use values like `min-h-10` is by [using custom values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height#using-custom-values) where you can customize your `min-height` scale by editing `theme.minHeight` or `theme.extend.minHeight` in your `tailwind.config.js` file like take the following example.

Your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    maxHeight: {
      '10': '10px',
    }
  }
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="max-h-10 w-32 bg-red-400">
  I'm an element!
</div>
```

See the [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WFkU23yuRM)

Or if you need to use a value once that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, you can use [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height#arbitrary-values) like below:

```html
<div class="max-h-[10px] w-32 bg-red-400">
  I'm an element!
</div>
```

See the [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aFuAxVdArq)

In my answer, I've only used examples for [`max-height`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height) and [`min-height`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height) but it doesn't differ anything from [`min-width`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width) and [`max-width`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width).

Comment: Very clear! Thankyou

Comment: I'm so sorry for forgetting that! I did it now!

Answer (score 1):

In Tailwind CSS, you can set your custom values like this:

```html
<div class="flex-col justify-center items-center">
    <div class="min-h-[100px] min-w-[100px] border bg-blue-300 block">
        h
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make spacing work for max/min width/height

```
theme:{
  extend: {
      minHeight: {
        ...defaultTheme.height,
      },
      minWidth: {
        ...defaultTheme.width,
      },
  }
}
```

if it not work, use this

```
theme:{
  extend: {
      minHeight: ({ theme }) => ({
        ...theme('height'),
      }),
      minWidth: ({ theme }) => ({
        ...theme('width'),
      }),

  }
}
```